# Eclipse - Button. EditTexts have exclimation marks on them

Tags: android, eclipse

I'm new to eclipse and integrated android.

Here i'm trying to make a simple basic project which takes username and password, and upon clicking the button displays a Toast message "Welcome".

But while i was designing the UI, i saw exclamation signs on every palette.

How can this be resolved . 
Thanks in advance.

Here is a screen https://www.dropbox.com/s/d66r6nv51xfnz5z/Untitled.png

Comment: have you tried hovering on these items? Or look in your warning/error log?

Comment: Just click on the sign to see what is the warning ? And whatever, they won't be visible in the final app.

Comment: it can happen for various reasons . They don't prevent you to run the code but if you still want to get rid of these you can hover over to warning icon and you will see the reason then fix it

Answer (score 0):

That means u hard code the text directly in the xml file.
please register those name in strings.xml file then the exclamation signs will gone.\
see some examples of android